# Predict the major product of the following reaction with mechanism

Tags: carbonyl-compounds, amines

[image]

I started to do the problem by coordinating H+ with the lone pair of oxygen then after that I can't proceed .please send the solution by show the detailed mechanism.

Comment: Are you sure the carbonyl will be protonated when there's an imine group around?

Comment: I think answer is (C), which is impossible to achieve under given conditions.

Answer (score 1):

There are two equally important path for the given reaction: (i) Via protonation of imine $\ce{N}$; and (ii) Via protonation of keto $\ce{O}$.

(i) Protonation of imine $\ce{N}$ would end up with 1,4-addition to give structure (A), which rearranges to structure (B) via keto-enol tautomerism.

(ii) It is also possible that Protonation can be undergone through keto $\ce{O}$, which would end up with 1,4-addition followed by keto-enol tautomerism to give structure (D). See the depicted arrow-pushing mechanism below:

[image: possible products]

To get structure (C), it need to have 1,6-addition, which is impossible. Therefore, the answer is (C).

Comment: Did you mean, therefore the answer is (B)?

Comment: @user55119: I meant answer is (C). Asking is "which is X *cannot* be?"!